# Bash PROMPT_COMMAND used to show git branch before git update to 1.8

Tags: git, bash

I had obtained this bash code a while ago from some blog article and it used to show my current git branch and dirty status in my prompt. After updating git from 1.7.11.4 to 1.8.5.4 it no longer shows the branch or dirty status.

This is how my prompt used to look:

```
[~/some/project (master)↑⚡] ->
```

It shows the (current git branch), the arrow means I'm ahead of the remote and I should push, and the lightning bolt means I have uncommited changes.

After the update, it's just this (without any changes to the repo):

```
[~/some/project] ->
```

Here is the code from my .bash_profile:

```
        RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
     YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
        GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
       BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
  LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
      WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
 LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
 COLOR_NONE="\[\e[0m\]"

function parse_git_branch {
  git rev-parse --git-dir &> /dev/null
  git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
  branch_pattern="^# On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"
  remote_pattern="# Your branch is (.*) of"
  diverge_pattern="# Your branch and (.*) have diverged"

  if [[ ! ${git_status}} =~ "working directory clean" ]]; then
    state="${RED}⚡"
  fi

  # add an else if or two here if you want to get more specific
  if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${remote_pattern} ]]; then
    if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} == "ahead" ]]; then
      remote="${YELLOW}↑"
    else
      remote="${YELLOW}↓"
    fi
  fi

  if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${diverge_pattern} ]]; then
    remote="${YELLOW}↕"
  fi

  if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${branch_pattern} ]]; then
    branch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo " (${branch})${remote}${state}"
  fi
}

function prompt_func() {
    previous_return_value=$?;
    prompt="${TITLEBAR}${BLUE}[${YELLOW}\w${GREEN}$(parse_git_branch)${BLUE}]${COLOR_NONE} "
    if test $previous_return_value -eq 0
    then
        PS1="${prompt}➔ "
    else
        PS1="${prompt}${RED}➔${COLOR_NONE} "
    fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_func
```

I'm not very good with bash so can anyone spot the problem, or have a better solution?

I'm playing around with the bash code but can't figure it out yet. Help, please.

- Mac 10.9.1
- Git 1.8.5.4
- iTerm 2

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was easier than I thought. Turns out the problem was that in git 1.7 the git status command would echo out:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

With a leading `#` in front. Now git 1.8 outputs the same except without that `#`.

So all I had to do was change these lines:

```
branch_pattern="^# On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"
remote_pattern="# Your branch is (.*) of"
diverge_pattern="# Your branch and (.*) have diverged"
```

to:

```
branch_pattern="^On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"
remote_pattern="Your branch is (.*) of"
diverge_pattern="Your branch and (.*) have diverged"
```

Removed the `#`s and everything works again.

Answer (score 1):

note, this pattern still fails:

```
remote_pattern="Your branch is (.*) of"
```

new git output looks like:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
```

so the pattern should be changed to:

```
remote_pattern="Your branch is (behind|ahead) "
```